# how to keep elements inline in bootstrap when it is mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_form&stacked=h

Please refer the above link, when the screen becomes mobile the search button comes down.

How do I keep it inline?

parent element as below

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
               
    
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-8">
search bar here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <form class="form-inline col-12 " action="/action_page.php">
            <input class="form-control col-md-4 col-7 mr-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-success col-md-2 col-3" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Navbar Forms</h3>
        <p>Use the .form-inline class to align form elements side by side inside the navbar.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**description**
Add col classes to tag input & button. Those change from desktop to mobile, so you have to adjust width for both.

- In this case I used 7 cols for input and 3 for buttom, adding a right
  margin separator of 2 (mr-2). This applies for mobile.
- For desktop, I used 4 cols for input + 2 for buttom.

Important note: I copied code form the link, I was not use your code directly.